# Maintain a session across multiple instances of app when called from same shell

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to have data (generated by an application only after its launch) persisted across multiple invocations of an application, but only when they're started from the same shell session.

One possible way to do that would be to pass the data back from the application to the calling shell, but since environment variable changes are only passed from parent to child, I don't know how to implement that.

Practical example:
There is `job` command that create subdirectory with current datetime and does work inside. Sometimes job needs to be killed and restarted, so it need directory where if finished, like `job --resume 21Fri_1849/data`. I would like to save `21Jan_1849/data` so I don't have to check and type it each time I need to resume job. If I created something like .last_job, and wanted to restart job in another session, it could resume wrong (last) job, so files are not solution (AFAIK).

How can this be done?

Comment: Post some code...

Comment: That said, what's a "session"? If they're per-TTY, store `.last_job.$(tty)`. If you want to key off the shell's PID, `.last_job.$PPID`. If you want the shell to control what's considered the same session, have it export a variable used to name the last_job file. Etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Makes sense, but such files may be accidentally reused by another shell (with same tty or PID), and needs to be manually cleared. Am I right?

Comment: @Robert there is no code so far, just program that when called `job` creates random dir, and another command `job --resume random_dir`, that needs directory created by previous command.

Comment: @Shadow, ...that's why I suggested exporting a variable from the shell. `export session_uuid=$(uuidgen)` in your dotfiles, and every shell instance has a new and unique session.

Comment: @Shadow, ...you might consider looking at how programs like `ssh-agent` work -- it's very much the same thing (setting environment variables in the shell that point to a daemon instance that processes started by that shell are expected to use).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I could generate session_id in shell, but then I need to deal with temporary files. Is writing them to /tmp sufficient (I don't care about security), in other words - won't admin stab me?

Comment: @Shadow, see https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html -- to me, this sounds like a use case for `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. If it's not set, see https://serverfault.com/questions/388840/good-default-for-xdg-runtime-dir

Comment: A case could also be made for `XDG_CACHE_DIR` / `$HOME/.cache/yourprog/...`, discussed in the same spec linked previously. BTW, one way to support cleanup is to have each shell hold a file handle on its UUID, so you can look for unreferenced files to figure out which sessions you can delete (as with `fuser`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only trying to target Linux, there are a fair number of tricks available here. Consider this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
current_boot_id=$(</proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id)

# honor myprog_shell_pid if set and valid, fall back to PPID otherwise
if [[ $myprog_shell_pid ]] && [[ -e /proc/$myprog_shell_pid/stat ]]; then
  parent_pid=$myprog_shell_pid
else
  parent_pid=$PPID
fi

parent_start_time=$(awk '{print $22}' "/proc/$parent_pid/stat")
mkdir -p "$HOME/.cache/myscript-sessions"
data=$HOME/.cache/myscript-sessions/${current_boot_id}:${parent_pid}:${parent_start_time}
```

Now, we have a data file name that changes:

- When we're rebooted (because `current_boot_id` is updated)
- If we're run from a different shell (because our `PPID` changes).
- If we're run from a different shell with the same PID (because the start time for the parent PID will be different).

...and you can easily delete files with the wrong boot id (because the system rebooted), or with names that refer to PID/start-time combinations that don't exist.

One caveat is that by default, this is sensitive to being called by subshells (`output=$(./yourprog)` will have a different PPID than `./yourprog` will), but if the parent shell runs `export myprog_shell_pid=$$`, that issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You're crossing over to where you need a simple job management engine instead of just shell.  Using 'make' and writing Makefiles is the probably the simplest way to set this up.  You can write a rule that tells how to turn a stage 1 file into a stage 2 file based on file extension, and then make will know how far things got and how to resume next time you run it.

Comment: My application cannot be broken into parts so far, so I think makefile is not an option. I can add some code, but not such huge modification.